# Is it possible to delete a constraint after replacing it in another constraint?

Tags: optimization, constraints

I have an optimization problem that has the following two constraints:

$$
\text{minimize} \, S \\
\text{Subject to:} \\
(1) \,\frac{t}{w_{0}} \le S \\
(2)A \times B \le t
$$

Is it correct to divide both sides of constraint $(2)$ by $\frac{1}{w_{0}}$ like this:

$$
\frac{1}{w_{0}} \times A \times B \le \frac{t}{w_{0}} \le S \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{w_{0}} \times A \times B \le S
$$

and delete constraint $(1)$, making the problem like this: 
$$
\text{minimize} \, S \\
\text{Subject to:} \\
\frac{1}{w_{0}} \times A \times B \le S
$$

I actually want to delete variable $t$ from the optimization problem.

Comment: Assuming $w_0 > 0$ and $t$ does not occur anywhere else in the problem, then yes, this is correct.

Comment: It depends: if $S$ is an expression involving $t$, then you are now "forgetting" that $t$ is bounded from above/below as well. If $t$ no longer appears in the quantity to be optimized, then that should be fine.